# No error for the query in sql but there is no output

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am going to give the bookname from text box in asp.net to the tbllendinginfo.using that name i want the bookId from another table tblbookinfo and it is to be automatically stored to the tbllendinginfo.the following code does not show any error.

```
create procedure inserttotbllendinginfo
@bookname nvarchar(50),
@studentid int,
@noofbooks int,
@dateoflending date
as
begin
update tbllendinginfo
set BookId=bi.BookId
from tbllendinginfo li
inner join tblbookinfo as bi
on(bi.Name)=@bookname
insert into tbllendinginfo (StudentId,NoofBooks,DateOfLending) values(@studentid,@noofbooks,@dateoflending)
end
```

this is my procedure. Whwn i executethe output "O rows affected"
please help me

Comment: Did you tried running it on prompt or MSSM specially your update statement?

Comment: I dont know how ot run in prompt or MSSM.Can you please tell me

Comment: Why are first updating tbllendinginfo and then inserting into it? There seems to be something slightly off there. FWIW, I would recommend not using the tbl prefix on table names and add some capitalization to make it easier to read. LendingInfo is a lot more clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this....

```
   update li
    set li.BookId=bi.BookId
    from tbllendinginfo li
    inner join tblbookinfo as bi
    on li.BookId=bi.BookId where bi.Name=@bookname
```

Comment: First you check that tblbookinfo Contain the name that You are passed and second thin Check Record after the inner join ....simple try this    select *
      from tbllendinginfo li
    inner join tblbookinfo as bi
    on li.BookId=bi.BookId where bi.Name=@bookname

Comment: It shows the result as a joint of two table columns only and there is no data in the table

Comment: how update is possible ...!!!!!so you have problem Either with inner join or @ Bookname parameter .....it means there is no common bookid in both table or  tblbookinfo table doesn't have name of @ bookname ...